# Where can I find historical statistics about Catholic monasticism?

Tags: catholic-church, resource, monastery

I'm reading a book on monasticism ([The World of Medieval Monasticism](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_World_of_Medieval_Monasticism.html?id=-Us2DAAAQBAJ), by Melville) and the author very often makes statements like "by year X, there were Y monasteries in Europe with around Z members" (sometimes offering sources). I was prompted to search online for historical statistics on monasteries (by order, gender, country, etc). From the book I'm reading as well as online searches, the information (at least to a general degree) seem to be around (e.g. a paper with statistics about women communities for the period 500-1100 AD is [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3174551)). However, these sources seem to be partial. **I was not able to find a resource collating in a systematic way all the information.**

Are you aware of any such resource (reference book, database)?

Comment: The author, [Gert Melville](https://history.ua.edu/tag/gert-melville/), is a professor of history so there is presumably a bibliography. At the very least provide that in the question and highlight in what ways it is inadequate for your needs.

Comment: Also look at the notes towards the end of the book. When present, such notes tie bibliographic references with whatever was on the page, without cluttering a book's pages like they do in pop culture psychology books.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The book is indeed full of sources. I mentioned one example of a source with **partial** information. I stated that the information seems to be around. I was not able to find a resource collating in a systematic way all the information. That's what I want.

Comment: @luchonacho that information should be in the question.

Answer (score 3):

For recent history, the [*Annuarium Statisticum Ecclesiæ*](https://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/en/bollettino/pubblico/2017/04/06/170406e.html) (an annual almanac) contains information about numbers of priests and religious.